# Controlling compiler flags in the Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I know I can use `LOCAL_CFLAGS` to pass arguments to the compiler. However, `ndk-build` is inserting options after my `LOCAL_CFLAGS`, and therefore they take precedence. For example, I want to specify `-Ofast`, but `ndk-build` adds `-O2` after my own flags, and since only the last option is the one that has any effect, I'm unable to test my code with certain optimization flags set.

Is there any way to either force my `LOCAL_CFLAGS` to be the last options on the build command, or to disable `ndk-build` from using certain flags?

For example, my `LOCAL_CFLAGS` is set to:

```
-Wall -Wno-psabi -Ofast -D CP_USE_DOUBLES=0 -D USE_CHIPMUNK
```

And the call to `g++` that `ndk-build` makes is:

> `/Library/Android/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/native-activity/Main.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -Ijni -Ijni/Chipmunk/include/chipmunk -I/Library/Android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/android/native_app_glue -I/Library/Android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport -I/Library/Android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include -Ijni -DANDROID -Wall -Wno-psabi -Ofast -D CP_USE_DOUBLES=0 -D USE_CHIPMUNK -Wa,--noexecstack  -frtti  -O2 -DNDEBUG -g   -I/Library/Android/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/Main.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/native-activity/Main.o`

There's a lot in there, but specifically notice that it first specifies `-Os`, then there's my `-Ofast`, and then after that there's `-O2`. Why it specifies `-Os` if it's going to later say `-O2`, I don't know, but I'm frustrated my `-Ofast` is being overridden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add

```
APP_CFLAGS += -Ofast
```

to your Application.mk.

It will not stop NDK from adding `-O2` but it will place your flag after the NDK's.
This works for me with NDK r8b.

Comment: It doesn't for me, for some reason. I'll edit my question to show the actual call to `g++`. `-O2` is still after `-Ofast`.

Comment: Could you post your Application.mk file?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I completely misread that and saw it as `LOCAL_CFLAGS`. That worked for me, thanks!