# How to get the -fpermissive flag to take effect?

Tags: c++, makefile, android-ndk, preprocessor-directive, android.mk

I'm building a library in c++ with the NDK (Android). The output tells me that some code is flagged as an error but could be suppressed by using the -fpermissive flag.  At least that's how it looks to me.  The output is:

```
MyClass.cpp:412:1: error: jump to label 'extractUp' [-fpermissive]
 extractUp:
 ^
jni/../../../../SharedSrc/MyClass.cpp:469:10: error:   from here [-fpermissive]
     goto extractUp;
          ^
jni/../../../../SharedSrc/MyClass.cpp:402:31: error:   skips initialization of 'Foo* ISC'
      Foo *ISC = new Foo;
```

The code that's causing the error isn't relevant here as the question I'm asking is what might be preventing the -fpermissive flag from taking effect.  The makefile (Android.mk) seems to be correct in how it is setting the flag but I don't know much about make files:

```
add_definitions(-DFPERMISSIVE=1)
```

I've also tried -Dfpermissive in case all caps were not allowed, and have tried adding it to LOCAL_CFLAGS with:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Dfpermissive
```

and

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DFPERMISSIVE
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually that's not a flag definition so you shouldn't use `-Dflagname` but just `-fpermissive`, which is a flag to the compiler.

`-Dflagname` has the effect of `#define flagname` which is not what you need to do.

By the way the `-fpermissive` doesn't suppress errors, it just downgrades them to warning.

Comment: could you be specific on how to use it as just -fpermissive?  I changed the LOCAL_CFLAGS line in my example to just use -fpermissive and it now complains "unrecognized command line option '-fpermissive'".

Comment: I also tried just adding -fpermissive on the command line. I ran "ndk-build -fpermissive" but it responds "make: permissive: No such file or directory" and a second line after that "make: *** No rule to make target 'permissive'. Stop." How to make it recognize -fpermissive?

Comment: Did you try with `APP_CFLAGS`?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323655/controlling-compiler-flags-in-the-android-ndk

Comment: Yes, with same result as reported in initial post.

Comment: I have been using NDK_LOG=1 when I build which indeed gives more verbose output, but not sure if that info is what you want.  How do I get the "effective build command"?

Answer (score 0):

You can add APP_CFLAGS += or APP_CPPFLAGS += in your Application.mk file.

For C++ code you need to use APP_CPPFLAGS += -fpermissive

Where as for C code you use APP_CFLAGS += -fpermissive

It is also possible to use both of them in your Application.mk file if your project contains both codes.